# jQuery Selector Returning "NaN" -- Intermittent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, nan

Got this really weird timing issue going on.

```
var myVar = myContainer.find("input, textarea, button, select");
console.log("myContainer", myContainer.length, "myVar", myVar.length);
if (!myVar.length) {
   debugger;
}
```

Object myVar contains the following when the debugger is hit:

```
myVar {
       NaN: HTMLInputElement
//all other jQuery member data here
}
```

How could the member element possibly be "NaN"?!

Occasionally, we're seeing "NaN" for myVar (the result of a find operation).
myContainer ALWAYS has a length of 1. So it's a valid jQuery object....

How is this possible? I'd think that if the myContainer object was bad in some way, it's length would be 0 or I'd get a different more explicit error.

We're aware that this is a timing issue, mostly because it's so intermittent. About 1/10 times or so this happens.

Any suggestions would be awesome! :D

Comment: It's possible that `myContainer` is some other object such as an array with a `length` > 0 .

Comment: Something interesting you might find is, the jQuery `find()` function does not work with multiple element types in its argument in many browsers. I had to change my code several days ago because of that. It only took first or last element (I don't remember well which) into consideration.